# Why does using REPLACE over SELECT cause div by zero exception?

Tags: mysql

I have a somewhat complicated SQL statement that used to work for years AFAIK:

```
REPLACE INTO aggregate (
    channel_id, type, timestamp, value, count
) 
SELECT channel_id, 1 AS type, MAX(agg.timestamp) AS timestamp, 
    COALESCE(
        SUM(agg.val_by_time) / (
            MAX(agg.timestamp) - MIN(agg.prev_timestamp)
        ), 
        AVG(agg.value)
    ) AS value, 
    COUNT(agg.value) AS count 
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        channel_id, timestamp, value, 
        value * (timestamp - @prev_timestamp) AS val_by_time, 
        COALESCE(@prev_timestamp, 0) AS prev_timestamp, 
        @prev_timestamp := timestamp 
    FROM data CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT 
        @prev_timestamp := UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
            DATE_ADD(
            FROM_UNIXTIME(
                MAX(timestamp) / 1000, 
                "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00"
            ), 
            INTERVAL 1 minute
            )
        ) * 1000 
        FROM aggregate 
        WHERE type = 1 AND aggregate.channel_id = '19'
    ) AS vars 
    WHERE channel_id = '19' AND timestamp >= IFNULL(
        (
        SELECT 
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
            DATE_ADD(
                FROM_UNIXTIME(
                MAX(timestamp) / 1000, 
                "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00"
                ), 
                INTERVAL 1 minute
            )
            ) * 1000 
        FROM 
            aggregate 
        WHERE 
            type = 1 
            AND aggregate.channel_id = '19'
        ), 
        0
    ) 
    AND timestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
        DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00")
    ) * 1000
) AS agg 
GROUP BY channel_id, 
YEAR(
    FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp / 1000)
), 
DAYOFYEAR(
    FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp / 1000)
), 
HOUR(
    FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp / 1000)
), 
MINUTE(
    FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp / 1000)
)
```

It basically creates a materialized view for timeseries data aggregated by minute. Recently this statement has started to error:

```
SQLSTATE[22012]: Division by zero: 1365 Division by 0
```

Looking into it I've removed the `REPLACE INTO` part to see the actual data and voila- no error (Mysql 8.0.16).

Any idea why the only interesting division in the SQL statement might behave differently when `REPLACE` is used?

Answer (score 0):

If `MAX(agg.timestamp)` and `MIN(agg.prev_timestamp)` are the same for a particular channel, this expression

```
MAX(agg.timestamp) - MIN(agg.prev_timestamp)
```

will be zero, so this

```
SUM(agg.val_by_time) / (MAX(agg.timestamp) - MIN(agg.prev_timestamp))
```

will explode with a divide by zero error.

Comment: Absoluteley, yes. But that should also explode when I omit the replace into part?

Comment: There's too much irrelevant code to be much help, and you haven't shown any example data; try making a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Keep stripping down the SQL until the absolute minimum remains that still have the problem. Do that with the data too. The SQL and data required to reproduce the problem should be so small that the cause and solution are obvious.

Comment: Thats unfortunately hard to as the REPLACE will break the test case once it succeeds. I understand that REPLACE itself should not change the SELECT's behaviour.